# How to do Streaming at controller layer Spring

Tags: java, spring

I am developing one simple Java Spring application and trying to get all the saved Order from database. Application flow is simple though have around 100k record in database. I used streaming at JPA layer from DB to application data is coming fine.
But when this start transferring from Controller to client something it throws 502 response. Following is piece of code for all three layer.

Could someone help to solve this problem? Requirement all this data should come without using any filter or pagination.

```
@GetMapping(produces = "application/json")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public Resources getOrders() {
        return userService.getOrders();
    }

    @Transactional
    public Resources getOrders() {
        Stream<Orders> orders = streamAll();

        List<Order> orderList = new ArrayList<>();
        orderList.addAll(orderConverter.createFromEntities(orders));

        Resource resources = new Resource();
        resources.setResources(orderList);
        return resources;
    }

    @Query("select u from Order")
    Stream<Orders> streamAll();
```

Comment: Do you have the source code on `gitHub`? Does not seem to be a problem with the code but a proxy or gateway your server maybe using.

Comment: is that means gateway timeout configuration.

Comment: Can you mock your `userService.getOrders()` to return small number of records like 4 or 5 and see the response of your controller, just to be sure the error is not because of the large number of records your controller is returning.

Comment: hi akash, this issue only comes when we have large number of records in db. I am sure this is because of data and proxy.  But is it possible to stream data from controller layer to client.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a 502 response because your JVM is exhausted in memory. Use streaming detached objects at the repository layer.

First, check if your database supports fetching a result set through streaming data. For example, MYSQL supports it using a read-only session and fetch size with value Integer.MIN_VALUE [1].

Later, customize your repository to open a stateless session with StatelessSession interface [2]. Thanks to this interface you are getting objects detached, so Hibernate releases it immediately and no cost memory in cache.

If you need to make changes, remember again, your objects are detached. You need open another session (read-write). Your objects will be saved with these session, and after saving it, you must detach it manually.

This example covers the first requirement:

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

public void stackoverflowQuestion() {
        Session currentSession = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
        ScrollableResults rows = currentSession
            .createQuery("SELECT u FROM Order", Orders.class)
            .setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE)
            .scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY);

        while (rows.next()) {
            Orders order = (Orders) rows.get(0);
                ...
            }
}
```

[1] https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-implementation-notes.html

[2] https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en-US/html/batch.html